# Array for multiple inputs

Tags: java, arrays

Can somebody help me with a program in java that will accepts ten students name, their matric number and also their scores for ten courses and also determine their grade using, the code I uses but it's not a array

```
import java.util.*;
public class GPACALCULATOR {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Unit,Tunit=0;
    double Gp,Tgp=0;
    int Score;
    double Sgp = 0;
    double Gpa= 0;
    String Course, Grade, Name, Mnum;
    System.out.println("PLEASE INPUT YOUR NAME");
    Name= s.next();
     System.out.println("PLEASE INPUT THE LAST TWO DIGITS OF YOUR MATRIC NUMBER");
    Mnum= s.next();
    System.out.println("HOW MANY COURSE ARE YOU OFFERING");
    int C= s.nextInt();



    for (int X= 0; X<C; X++)
    {
        System.out.println("ENTER COURSE CODE");
        Course= s.next();
        System.out.println("ENTER HE COURSE UNIT");
        Unit= s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("ENTER THE COURSE SCORE");
        Score= s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" ");

        if (Score>=70)
        {
            Grade= "A";
            Gp = 4.0;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        }


        else if (Score>=65)
        {
            Grade= "AB";
            Gp = 3.5;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

       else if (Score>=60)
        {
            Grade= "B";
            Gp = 3.0;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=55)
        {
            Grade= "C";
            Gp = 2.5;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=50)
        {
            Grade= "C";
            Gp = 2.0;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=45)
        {
            Grade= "CD";
            Gp = 1.5;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=40)
        {
            Grade= "D";
            Gp = 1.0;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=35)
        {
            Grade= "E";
            Gp = 0.5;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 

        else if (Score>=40)
        {
            Grade= "F";
            Gp = 0.0;
            Tgp= Gp * Unit;
            System.out.println("COURSE " + "SCORE " + "GRADE " + "GP ");

            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(Course+" "+Unit+ " " +Score+" "+Grade+" "+Gp+" ");
            System.out.println(" ");

        } 
        Tunit+=Unit;
        Sgp+=Tgp;

    }
        Gpa= Sgp/Tunit;
        System.out.println(Name);
        System.out.println("F/HD/15/32100"+Mnum);
        System.out.println("THE CGPA OF THE ABOVE NAME STUDENT IS "+ Gpa);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to create a class Student, and create data fields using their name, course numbers, number grade of a given course, etc. Above the code shown (in whatever IDE, compiler, etc, that you're using), it could start out something like this (I think, so someone correct me if I'm wrong):

```
Class Student{
   private String name;
   private int matricNum;
   private int courseLoad;

   //then arrange for the getters and setters
   public String getName(){ return name;}
   public int getMatricNum(){ return matricNum;}
   public int getCourseLoad(){ return courseLoad;}


   public void setName(String name){ this.name=name;}
   public void setMatricNum(int matricNum){ this.matricNum = matricNum;}
   public void setCourseLoad(int courseLoad){ this.courseLoad = courseLoad;}

   public Student(String name, int matricNum, int courseLoad){
       this.name = name;
       this.matricNum = matricNum;
       this.courseLoad = courseLoad;
   }
```

Repeat this to create a course class, with data fields for the course code, the unit number, and the score of the course. After both are finished, create arrays of both class types:

```
public Student[] students = new Student[10]; //This creates a student array
 of ten students that will allow you to enter the above data for each student.


public Course[] courses = new Course[(Enter some number here that will accommodate the total number of courses that every student contains)];
```

What I think is an efficient solution for this is to enter the data for the initial student array, followed by the a given amount of courses for said student, and then repeat this.

Then, when checking the grades, iterate through the Course[] array based on a student's entries, and then calculate the grade for each class.

On a different note, System.out.println(); doesn't need any spaces in it to be executed. It's a longer form of the new line character "\n" and therefore the print statement could just be written:

System.out.println();

Anyway, this process may sound tedious, but I think this would suffice for what you have in mind in terms of what you're trying to accomplish as well as in terms of efficiency.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have you run d code and see my understand my expected output?

Comment: I understand the output, yes. You want to store 10 students and their data in a sort of array, and then with their own classes, course units, and GPA for each class? What I set up in my answer is a way to create a "database" that stores this information for you and so that you can print it out for each student. Does what I say make sense?